# How to filter out Empty records?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter out this data. I want to get output with only rows with expiration date is blank.

I tried command with dplyr library, but this command is not working:

```
Input = import("IEL_HS_CA_CAP_F_BI.xlsx", skip=1); #Get original data
Input1 <- filter(Input, Input$EXPIRATION_DATE == NULL ); #This command is throwing error
```

[image: Input Data]

How do I filter the data so that output will have data with Expiration_Date blank?

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Output]

P.S. : The filter must be on Expiration_Date. Actual dataset is huge, I just uploaded sample image here. Don't suggest filtering other columns.

Comment: Maybe sth. like `Input[!Input$EXPIRATION_DATE == "", ]`, hard to tell without a small reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, first set empty cells to NA, by input <- input %>% mutate_all(na_if,""), and then you can do na.omit()

Comment: try `filter(Input, is.null(EXPIRATION_DATE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out to get this dataset through dplyr. Getting `NULL` values aside is not very easy in this library, so I used the following code:

```
Input = import("IEL_HS_CA_CAP_F_BI.xlsx", skip = 1); #Get Data
Input1 <- Input[complete.cases(Input[ , c('EXPIRATION_DATE')]), ] #Get the data with Expiration date Complete Cases Only
Input2 = setdiff(Input, Input1) #Remove the complete cases from Expiration date, to get NULL value dataset
```

Input2 returned the `Expiration_date` = `Null` data.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use dplyr in this way:

```
input1 = input |>
filter(!is.null(EXPIRATION_DATE))
```

Comment: This only works if the column is not a character. If it is a character, the empty value will not be a technical NULL